# Kafka Avro Deserialization Issue (java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: java.util.UUID.<init>(java.lang.String)

Tags: java, apache-kafka, avro, kafka-consumer-api

I am attempting to deserialize an Avro object from a Kafka stream and am seeing:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:   java.util.UUID.<init>(java.lang.String)
```

Java UUID lacks a default empty constructor and so it seems like I need to write a custom deserializer. I wrote a new class that extended `Deserializer<UUID>` but when debugging I did not break into that class. I want to use this deserializer along with a generic deserializer (I figured this is possible because it is with Jackson).

Am I missing something simple that I need to do?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I just needed to write a custom Avro encoder!

Comment: How did you write custom decoders/encoders? I'm having the same problem and documentation is sparse. Additionally, does this work with default UUID values?